# Arduino HID keyboard does not work

Tags: keyboard

I'm using a [ItsyBitsy 32u4](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3677), Adafruit says it can act as a USB HID keyboard. The mc is based on the 32u4 which the [Keyboard](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/usb/keyboard/) docs say are supported.

I have a simple sketch that prints "A" every second and should press "A". When I upload the sketch and connect to the serial port I see the print output but I don't get any key presses.

Any ideas? I'm on linux, I suspect that the controller doesn't register as a HID device, maybe I need UDEV rules or drivers?

EDIT: the keyboard works on a different computer.

```cpp
#include <Keyboard.h>
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Keyboard.begin();
  Serial.println("Start");
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("a");
  Keyboard.write('a');
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: you shoukd read the reference and study the examples

Comment: @Juraj I have, what do you think I missed?

Comment: it seemed you missed what is in the Answer. do you have a text editor open in foreground?

Comment: Yeah, I have a window focused that accepts and displays keyboard input. Typing on my actual keyboard displays the keys.

Comment: next I would try removing Serial from the sketch

Comment: removing serial didn't make a difference.

Comment: check the Device Manager if it has the HID device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some issue with my laptop, not controller or the sketch.

I tried the my board with another computer and it worked. I tried a commercial keyboard on my first computer it also didn't work.

Both keyboards work after a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Keyboard.press() expects a character, but you are passing a character array. Also Keyboard.press() only presses but does not release the key. Keyboard.releaseAll() can be used to release all keys.

I would try:

```
Keyboard.press('A') ;  //note the ' instead of "
Keyboard.releaseAll();
```

or preferably:

```
Keyboard.write('A');   //handles press and release of basic keys
```

Comment: I made an error when I created my simple repo sketch, but I have tried `Keyboard.press('A')` and `Keyboard.write('A')`. Neither work.

Comment: I also tried `Keyboard.write('a')` after reading keyboard.cpp and realizing that writing 'A' sends keypesses for `a` and the shift modifier.